# Можно ли из файла с музыкой получить ноты python

Tags: python, файлы, музыка

Я хочу написать ИИ для генерации музыки. Мне кажется для тренировки его мне понадобится разбить музыку на ноты, типа ля2-до3 и т.д. Что бы потом он сам смог написать её. Может нужно как то прочитать mid файл или типа того. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Лучше почитайте для начала про какие-то готовые решения на тему генерации музыки. Мне кажется, вы не с того конца к вопросу подошли )

Comment: я пытался, всё что я находил это не работающий код, со словами - вот и всё)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from music21 import converter, instrument, note, chord


notes = []
file = "songs/my_song.mid"

# Получаем все ноты и аккорды из файла
midi = converter.parse(file)
parts = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)


if parts:
    notes_to_parse = parts.parts[0].recurse()
else:
    notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes
for element in notes_to_parse:
    if isinstance(element, note.Note):
        # Добавляем "ноты, типа ля2-до3"
        notes.append(str(element.pitch))
    elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
        # Добавляем аккорды
        notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.pitches))

print(notes)
```

Так ты получишь ноты из midi файла в массив notes. Т.к. ты собрался обучать ИИ, нужно будет закодировать каждую ноту в нужную цифру.

```
note_to_int = {note: number for number, note in enumerate(sorted(set(notes)))}
for i in range(len(notes)):
    notes[i] = note_to_int.get(notes[i])
```

С этим уже можно работать

Comment: Спасибо большое!